# uwsgi.is_connected() delay with nginx

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, gevent

I have a setup with nginx, uwsgi, and gevent. When testing the setup's ability to handle premature client disconnects, I found that uwsgi isn't exactly responding in a timely manner.

This is how I detect that a disconnect has occurred inside of my python code:

```
While True:
    if 'uwsgi' in sys.modules:
        import uwsgi #@UnresolvedImport
        fileDescriptor = uwsgi.connection_fd()
        if not uwsgi.is_connected(fileDescriptor):
            logger.debug("Connection was lost (client disconnect)")
            break
```

So when uwsgi signals a lost of connection, I break out of this loop. There's also a call to gevent.sleep(2) at the bottom of the loop to prevent hammering the CPU.

With that in place I have nginx logging the close connection like this:

```
2016/08/16 19:23:23 [info] 32452#0: *1 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending to client, client: 192.168.56.1, server: <removed>, request: "GET /myurl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8070", host: "<removed>:8443"
```

nginx is immediately aware of the disconnect when it produces this log entry, it's within milliseconds of the client disconnecting. Yet uwsgi doesn't seem to be aware of the disconnect until seconds, sometimes almost a minute later at least in terms of notifying my code:

```
DEBUG  - Connection was lost (client disconnect) - 391 ms[08/16/16 19:24:04 UTC])
```

The uwsgi.log file created via daemonize suggests it somehow saw it a second before nginx but somehow waited half a minute to actually tell my code:

```
[pid: 32208|app: 0|req: 2/2] 192.168.56.1 () {32 vars in 382 bytes} [Tue Aug 16 19:23:22 2016] GET /myurl => generated 141 bytes in 42030 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 115 bytes (4 switches on core 999
```

This is my setup in nginx:

```
upstream bottle {
    server 127.0.0.1:8070;
}

server {
    listen       8443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key;

    server_name  <removed>;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            #proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            uwsgi_buffering off;
            uwsgi_ignore_client_abort off;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
            proxy_cache off;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            #uwsgi_read_timeout 5m;
            #uwsgi_send_timeout 5m;
            uwsgi_pass bottle;
    }
}
```

The odd part to me is how the timestamp from uwsgi is saying it saw it right when nginx did, however it doesn't write that entry until my code sees it ~30 seconds later. It appears from my perspective, that uwsgi is essentially lying or locking it up, yet I can't find any errors from it.

Any help is appreciated. I've attempted to remove any buffering and delays from nginx without any success.